# Snap SVG tag <Set > in javascript

Tags: svg, snap.svg

With SVG I can blink the border with this tag :

```
<circle cy="33" cx="33" class="mark" r="25" stroke="red">
   <set id="show" attributeName="stroke-width" attributeType="CSS" begin="0s; hide.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
   <set id="hide" attributeName="stroke-width" attributeType="CSS" to="5px" begin="show.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
</circle >
```

with that the circle's border blinks.

see the Jsffidle : http://jsfiddle.net/noteStylet/Lwty3dv5/1/

My question is, how to create this tag  with the Javascript ?
To start it and stop it ...

thanks

Comment: create the tag with document.createElementNS

Comment: I tried with document.createElementNS, the element <set> is insered bu the blink didn't work

Comment: Show us the non-working code so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/noteStylet/15sogdhy/](http://jsfiddle.net/noteStylet/15sogdhy/)
Here is the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo http has an initial h. I.e.

```
var set11 = document.createElementNS('ttp://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'set');
```

should be

```
var set11 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'set');
```

works for me on Firefox with that change.